# R6 classes, cloning, and a simple way of modifying the elements of the nested R6 object

Tags: r, r6

I am developing a structure of R6 classes. The idea is to have a **big** R6 class collecting many **small** objects of other R6 class types. The **big** object is the input to a function.

The point is that I would like to make it simple for users to modify the **small** objects within the **big** by developing R6 methods in the public object that would facilitate this.

Let me explain on the following example:

`ClassOne` object is one of the **small** objects:

```
> ClassOne = R6::R6Class(
+   "ClassOne",
+   
+   public = list(
+     element     = numeric(),
+     
+     initialize  = function() {
+       self$element <- 1
+     },
+     
+     set_element = function(value) {
+       if (!missing(value)) {
+         self$element <- value
+       }
+     }
+     
+   )
+ )
```

`ClassTwo` object is the **big** object that contains as `self$class_one_element` an object of class `ClassOne`.

```
> ClassTwo = R6::R6Class(
+   "ClassTwo",
+   
+   public        = list(
+     
+     class_one_element = list(),
+     
+     initialize  = function() {
+       self$class_one_element = ClassOne$new()
+     },
+     
+     get_class_one = function() {
+       self$class_one_element$clone()
+     }
+   )
+ )
```

Once the `ClassTwo` object is initiated:

```
> ct      = ClassTwo$new()
> ct$class_one_element$element
[1] 1
```

the method `get_class_one` is cloning the whole `self$class_one_element`:

```
> ct_co   = ct$get_class_one()
```

The method `set_element` is used to modify the **small** object:

```
> ct_co$set_element(2)
> ct_co$element
[1] 2
```

but despite the application of deep cloning, this operation is modifying only the `element` in the **small** object `ct_co` and not the corresponding `element` in the **big** object:

```
> ct$class_one_element$element
[1] 1
```

**THE QUESTION:** How to rewrite the `ClassTwo` (I guess) so that the sequence:

```
> ct      = ClassTwo$new()
> ct_co   = ct$get_class_one()
> ct_co$set_element(2)
```

is modifying `ct$class_one_element$element` as well?

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions!